# Как лучше всего сделать этот элемент?

Tags: html, css

Как лучше всего сделать этот элемент?(выделенный)[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: я 4 картинки(те ,которыевокруг стула) поставил на свои места а вот ка к ним текст приделать не понимаю(

Comment: добавил фото для примера

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код так, чтобы было видно что у вас уже сделано

Answer (score 2):

1. С помощью float

   ```css
   .block {
       overflow: auto;
       width: 232px;
   }
   .block-body {
       float: left;
       width: 170px;
   }
   .block-title {
       margin-bottom: 6px;
       font-weight: 600;
       text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   .block-icon {
       float: left;
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: red;
       margin-left: 12px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="block">
     <div class="block-body">
       <div class="block-title">Название блока</div>
       <div class="block-description">Описание данного блока</div>
     </div>
     <div class="block-icon"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. С помощью flexbox

   ```css
   .block {
       display: flex;
       width: 232px;
   }
   .block-body {
       width: 170px;
   }
   .block-title {
       margin-bottom: 6px;
       font-weight: 600;
       text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   .block-icon {
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: red;
       margin-left: 12px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="block">
     <div class="block-body">
       <div class="block-title">Название блока</div>
       <div class="block-description">Описание данного блока</div>
     </div>
     <div class="block-icon"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо,очень выручили!